# Passing multiple parameters to Rest API with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, rest, http

I am looking at designing a Rest search API which can accept multiple parameters as filters.

For example:

```
https://test/api/GetCustomer?Filter=”FirstName=test||LastName=test||telephone=043232323”
```

The above example will basically do a Or between the fields provided. It is passing the whole search string as one parameter. I want to be able to handle a more complex query as well as below:

```
https://test/api/GetCustomer?Filter=”(FirstName=test||LastName=test)&&telephone=043232323”
```

I am not too sure what is the best way to implement the endpoint, it would be easier from frond-end perspective to pass it as a single parameter and than do the parsing at the API level. But obviously it will require more effort to be able to parse the query specially if it is a bit more complex.

Is there a better way to implement the scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ease of use is one of top concerns when building a backend. Ease of implementation comes a distant second. Generally, it is much easier to compose a complex query than to parse it, so front-end developers would be able to build very powerful filtering code with a relatively small effort; this is a good thing.

Although doing the parsing right is somewhat complex, there are parsing tools for managing the complexity, such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). Although the learning curve for the new tool may be a little steep, in the end you would get a robust parsing library that makes it easy for front-end developers to consume your service.

Comment: Yeah it make sense to have the complex logic at the back-end.

Answer (score 1):

```
var queryString = this.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> QueryStringKeys = new 
List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

foreach (var pair in queryString)
{
    QueryStringKeys.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(pair.Key.ToString(), pair.Value));
}

Boolean firstvalue = true;
foreach (var keys in QueryStringKeys)
{
    //access key.Key and key.Value here to make dynamic query
}
```

This may not be the best way of doing it, but you can pass your results as normal query string variables

```
https://test/api/GetCustomer?FirstName=test&LastName=test&telephone=043232323
```

Comment: That will work but you cannot do complex operations as mentioned in my post. If I want to do or between firstName and LastName and than And on overall result with telephone. It cannot be achieved with above.